# how to reduce the font size in Grid view in Android?

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android.I just create the Grid view by using java code(not using xml design)
I need to reduce the font size of the Grid view .How to do this ?

Answer (score 7):

`GridView` does not have a font size, because `GridView` does not have a font, because `GridView` does not have any text.

If you are putting text into cells of a `GridView` by some sort of `Adapter`, then you need to modify your `Adapter` -- or the layout it is using for the cells -- to use a different font size.